# Insert bracket before a =TEXT()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, string-concatenation

I have a function that shows a begin- and end date. I wanted to have it between brackets in a cell:

```
=TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&")
```

I have the outher bracket already:

Example ->`01/01/2017 - 02/03/2017)`

But can't seem to try around and insert a bracket in the beginning.

I have tried:

```
=TEXT((A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&") 

=TEXT("("A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&") 

=TEXT(&"("A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&") 

"("=TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&")
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concatenate function.

Try this: (Convention Changed)

```
=concatenate("("; TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/jjjj")&" - "&TEXT(B1;"dd/mm/jjjj"); ")")
```

Comment: It shouldn't. What is the error being returned? Try checking you format_text?

Comment: @KahnKah change the **,** to **;** and try. Sorry i think i didn't notice the convention.,

Comment: Thanks Aly It works!! But what if I wanted to add another piece of tekst ? do I just add a `;` at the end?

Comment: @KahnKah Yes, just keep adding **;** and followed by whatever you wish to add. If text it needs to be wrapped around **' '**. Concatenate basically just combines everything into one string.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid string concatenation by making the extra characters part of the format mask used by the TEXT function. When using reserved characters or symbols that a format mask usually has another purpose for, precede them with a backslash to convert them to a 'string literal'.

```
=TEXT(A1; "\(dd/mm/jjjj - ")&TEXT(B1; "dd/mm/jjjj\)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative answer!